# ROR Association | undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

When i want to post my Post i have this:
[See the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inIZ4.png)

I use Rails on Archlinux.

**This is my Controller posts_controller.rb:**

```
module Admin
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_post, :set_categories, only: [:update, :edit, :destroy]
    layout 'back'
    def index
      @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')##.page(params[:page]).per(10)
    end

    def new
      @posts = Post.new
      @users = current_user
      @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    end

    def create
      @posts = Post.new(post_params)
      @posts.category_id = params[:category_id]
      if @posts.save
        redirect_to({action: :index}, success: "L'article à bien été crée")
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

    def edit
      @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    end

    def update
      if @posts.update(post_params)
        @posts.category_id = params[:category_id]
        redirect_to({action: :index}, success: "L'article à bien été modifié")
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @posts.destroy
      redirect_to({action: :index}, success: "L'article à bien été supprimé")
    end

    private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :meta, :description, :precontent, :content, :category_id)
    end

    def set_post
      @posts = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_categories
      @categories = Category.all
    end



  end
end
```

**This is my view:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Ajouter un article</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <%= simple_form_for @posts, url: [:admin, @posts], html:{class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :title, label: "Titre" %>
          <%= f.input :meta, label: "Meta TAGS (Référencement)" %>
          <%= f.input :description, label: "Description" %>
          <%= f.input :precontent, label: "Pré Contenu" %>
          <%= f.input :content, label: "Contenu" %>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter l'article</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Image & Catégories</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), class: 'form-control') %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is my model Post:**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged]
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**This is my model Category:**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

The relation ship is ManyToOne.
I want to use simple form with association but i dont know how its work properly.

Thank you in advance for your indulgence, i'm french and i'm not good in English.

Comment: Can you add the whole error dump here.. then we can quickly figure out from where it **booms** out?

Comment: I feel it fails, when edit/create fails.. so `@categories` has to be defined inside the create and update action too

Answer (score 0):

You have to define @categories (and any other variable you need for action "new") on action "create" if @post cannot be saved.

```
if @post.save
  ....
else
   @categories = Category.select(:name,:id).map{|c| [c.name, c.id]} #note the select, it will be faster than just calling all
   render :new
end
```

The same can be done for action "update", but I'd recommend to just redirect to the edit path of the @post instead of rendering :new (are you sure you want to render :new?)

Comment: when i put your line, i have no error but my posts is not posted i'm on the same page, see this: http://www.plixup.com/pics_core3/15351421607803Capture_du_2018_08_24_22_21_10.png

Comment: @post is not getting saved, you have to check if some validation is preventing that. You should inform the user the validation errors, you can also use byebug or pry-rails to debug the application in real time

Comment: I'm guessing that category is not actually being set, since it's outside the form. Check your logs, category_id must be empty. Just move the form initialization outside all fields or use the select's form attribute to point the form from outside https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp